# How would humans evolve on this planet?

Tags: planets, evolution

So I'm writing a story in which an advanced alien race, for reasons unknown, takes some humans from the Earth and leaves them on a far away habitable planet. Before droping them off, the aliens do some genetic modifications on the humans. For example, they alter their immune system so that they can be safe from most microbes on their new home. Plus they alter a bit what their stomach can digest so that they can eat other lifeforms, such as plants and animals (not all of them, some of them are venomous). After these modifications, they leave them on their new home. This planet has the following differences:

•It's a roughly Earth sized planet, only a tiny bit bigger in diameter and mass. (Gravity: 1,5 g)

•It has an oxygen rich atmosphere, though a bit thicker than Earth's.

•The climate is mostly tropical, and most of the planet's terrestrial surface is covered by mass rainforests.

•The planet orbits a small g-type star in the habitable zone.

Now my question is, how would humans adapt to this new confitions?

Comment: Your query is way, way too broad. If you have not already, please take a moment to review the [tour] and [help] so you can get a better idea how to write a question here.  You need to focus on one specific issue in one question.

Comment: A better (though still far too broad) question would be ‘how would my people not adapt’. Seriously: evolution is extremely unpredictable. Your folk could get shorter, get lighter, get heavier, get hairier, get fatter, get taller, some combination of these things, or they might develop parasol shaped hair simply because of sexual attraction. We can’t predict what might happen because *almost anything* could.

Answer (score 2):

The only relevant differences between our Earth before civilization and this other planet are gravity and atmospheric pressure.

The stronger gravity would favor bodies with more fat to absorb impact and more muscle to go around weighting more. In the future, those humans will look like sumo wrestlers.

The higher atmospheric pressure will require stronger lungs, which also favors more muscular builds.

As for the tropical forests... That has come and gone throughout prehistoric times. People will adapt to it with the finest stone age technologies: ropes,  nets and spears.

Comment: And this is very generalized as evolution can go in pretty much every direction. You can easily choose in a story how your species evolve as long as you follow the requirements of logic and science. Do also remember that evolution happens very very very slowly.